# vba look for multiple value in multiple column and return row number

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I got the following table below and I wanted to get the row number if for example `column(A:A)= "BTYA" and Column(B:B)="2" and Column(D:D)="Plan/actual Harvest Qty"` 

[image]

And below is my code and it gave me the location of the first occurrence instead of the next one. Any Help will be appreciated

```
Public Function Female_HarvestMaleQty_NotNull(ByVal Target As Range)
Const Col_Description = "D"
Const SheetName As String = "Test"

Dim Max_Growing_Days As Range
Dim Farm_Name As Range
Dim House_No As Range
Dim Description As Range

Dim FarmName As String
Dim HouseNo As Integer
Dim Descriptions As String
With Worksheets(SheetName)
House_name_no = .Cells(Target.Row, "A").Value & "-" &     .Cells(Target.Row,"B").Value
        With Worksheets("Farm Parameters").Rows("1:1")
            Set Max_Growing_Days = .Find(what:=House_name_no, _
            after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            lookat:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        End With

FarmName = .Cells(Target.Row, "A").Value
        With Worksheets("Farm Parameters").Columns("A:A")
            Set Farm_Name = .Find(what:=FarmName, _
            after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            lookat:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        End With
HouseNo = .Cells(Target.Row, "B").Value
        With Worksheets(SheetName).Columns("B:B")
            Set House_No = .Find(what:=HouseNo, _
            after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            lookat:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        End With
Descriptions = .Cells(Target.Row, "D").Value
        With Worksheets(SheetName).Columns("D:D")
            Set Description = .Find(what:=Descriptions, _
            after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            lookat:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        End With

        No_Days = Worksheets("Farm Parameters").Cells(8,   Max_Growing_Days.Column).Value - .Cells(Target.Row + 6, Target.Column).Value

 If .Cells(Target.Row, "A").Value = FarmName And .Cells(Target.Row, "B").Value = HouseNo And Description = "Plan/Actual Input DOC Qty" Then
MsgBox Description.Address

End If 
End With
End Function
```

Comment: What do you have in `Worksheets("Test")`? Your code does this: `Test.Cells(tr, "A") & "-" & Test.Cells(tr, "B")` and it implies that sheet Test has numbers in col A and B. Then the code does this: `FarmName = Test.Cells(tr, "A")` - implying that you want to extract "BTYA" from Test.ColA. If Col A contains numbers you cannot extract FarmName; if Col A has text you cannot subtract a number from text. Can you show part of the "Test" sheet as well?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fix the issue I mention in my comment to your post

Not knowing what "Test" sheet contains, adjust this code as needed:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Female_HarvestMaleQty_NotNull(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim max_Growing_Days As Range, house_name_no As Long, No_Days As Long
    Dim farm_Name As Range, house_No As Range, desc As Range
    Dim farmName As String, houseNo As Long, descs As String
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, wsFP As Worksheet, tr As Long, tc As Long, rowID As Long

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Test")
    Set wsFP = Worksheets("Farm Parameters")
    tr = Target.Row
    tc = Target.Column

    house_name_no = 2
    With wsFP.Rows("1:1")
        Set max_Growing_Days = ws1.UsedRange.Find(What:=house_name_no, _
            After:=ws1.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    End With

    farmName = "BTYA"
    houseNo = "2"
    descs = "Plan/actual Harvest Qty"

    No_Days = wsFP.Cells(8, max_Growing_Days.Column).Value - ws1.Cells(tr + 6, tc).Value

    rowID = getRowId(wsFP, farmName, houseNo, descs)
    MsgBox farmName & " || " & houseNo & " || " & descs & " ---> found on row: " & rowID

End Function
```

---

```
Public Function getRowId(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByVal farm As String, _
                         ByVal house As String, ByVal desc As String) As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ws.UsedRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=farm
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & house
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=desc

        If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count > 1 Then
            getRowId = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2).Row
        End If

        .AutoFilter
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

---

```
Public Sub testRow()
    Female_HarvestMaleQty_NotNull Worksheets("Test").Range("A5")
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer paul... i somehow need to get the row number on the same function to do another task..

Comment: what is your complete function? (your code is missing some lines, like function name, parameters used)

Comment: im sory if my code is not complete..i updated my codes already..pls check back.. i actually want to do some calculations if condition met.

Comment: see my edited answer, and make the necessary adjustments to accommodate data on Sheet Test